# Extracting a specific part from a string column in Pyspark

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, extract

In one of my projects, I need to transform a string column whose values looks like below

"[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12345_ID.xml.gz"

"[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12_ID.xml.gz"

I only need the alphanumeric values after "All/" and before "_ID", so the 1st record should be "abc12345" and second record should be "abc12".

in PySpark, I am using `substring` in `withColumn` to get the first 8 strings after "ALL/" position which gives me "abc12345" and "abc12_ID".

Then I am using `regexp_replace` in `withColumn` to check if `rlike` is "_ID$", then replace "_ID" with "", otherwise keep the column value. This is giving the expected result: "abc12345" and "abc12".

But is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this? In one [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract)?

```py
F.regexp_extract('col_name', r'ALL\/([^\W_]+)', 1)
```

Test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12345_ID.xml.gz",),
     ("[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12_ID.xml.gz",)],
    ["col_name"])

df = df.withColumn("col2", F.regexp_extract("col_name", r"ALL\/([^\W_]+)", 1))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------+--------+
# |col_name                                              |col2    |
# +------------------------------------------------------+--------+
# |[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12345_ID.xml.gz|abc12345|
# |[44252-565333] result[0] - /out/ALL/abc12_ID.xml.gz   |abc12   |
# +------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using the split function which was much easier. Using 1st split, I am splitting on "/ALL/" and taking the second part(split[1]). Using 2nd split, I am splitting on "_ID" taking  first part (split[0]). This solved this problem efficiently.